# scipy minimize inequality constraint function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints

I need to constrain my loss, so that the prediction is always positive.
So I have:

```
x = [1.0,0.64,0.36,0.3,0.2]
y = [1.0,0.5,0.4,-0.1,-0.2]
alpha = 0

def loss(w, x, y, alpha):
    loss = 0.0
    for y_i,x_i in zip(y,x):
        loss += ((y_i - np.dot(w,x_i)) ** 2)
    return loss + alpha * math.sqrt(np.dot(w,w))

res = minimize(loss_new_scipy, 0.0, args=(x, y, alpha))
```

Now i want to add the constraints, but i found mostly constraints that x is in between bounds, not `np.dot(w,x)>= 0`
How would such a constraint look like?

EDIT:
I want to use the constraints parameter in the scipy.optimize.minimize function, so I think it should look somehow like this:

```
def con(w,x):
    loss = 0.0
    for i_x in x:
         loss += (np.dot(w, i_x))
    return loss


cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con})
res = minimize(loss_new_scipy, 0.0, args=(x, y, alpha), constraints=cons)
```

also i removed the second constraint for simplicity

EDIT2:
I changed my problem to the following: constraint is w*x has to be greater than 1, and also changed the targets to all negatives. I also changed the args, so it runs now:

```
x = np.array([1.0,0.64,0.36,0.3,0.2])
y = [-1.0,-0.5,-0.4,-0.1,-0.2]
alpha = 0

def con(w,x,y,alpha):
    print np.array(w*x)
    return np.array((w*x)-1).sum()


cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con,'args':(x,y,alpha)})

def loss_new_scipy(w, x, y, alpha):
    loss = 0.0
    for y_i,x_i in zip(y,x):
        loss += ((y_i - np.dot(w,x_i)) ** 2)
    return loss + alpha * math.sqrt(np.dot(w,w))

res = minimize(loss_new_scipy, np.array([1.0]), args=(x, y, alpha),constraints=cons)
print res
```

But unfortunately the result for w is 2.0, which indeed is positive and looks like the constraint helped, since it is far away from fitting the function to the targets, but the predictions w*x are not all above 1.0

EDIT3:
i just realized that the sum of my predictions - 1 is equal to 0 now, but i want each prediction to be greater than 1.0
So with w = 2.0,

```
w*x = [ 2.00000001  1.28000001  0.72        0.6         0.4       ]
```

and

```
(w*x) - 1 = [ 1.00000001  0.28000001 -0.28       -0.4        -0.6       ]
```

which sum is equal to 0.0, but i want all predictions `w*x` to be greater than 1.0, so all 5 values in `w*x` should be at least 1.0

Comment: To possibly make this a more helpful question (ie, I found it useful along with the answer) is to perhaps remove the edit sections and re-write this in a more concise version  - otherwise, it is a tad difficult to follow despite this being a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your EDIT2 correctly, you are trying to minimize `|y - w*x|^2` as a function of a real parameter `w` (where `x` and `y` are vectors) with the constraint that `w*x` has all components larger than 1.

Now, the expression `|y - w*x|^2` is quadratic in `w` so it has a well defined global minimum (the factor in front of `w^2` is positive). However, the constraint on the components of `w*x` effectively imposes a minimum admissible value of `w` (since `x` is fixed), which is in this case `5`. Since the global minimum of the quadratic (unconstrained) function `|y - w*x|^2` is for your particular case around `np.dot(y,x)/np.dot(x,x)=-0.919`, the function is monotonically increasing for `w>=5`, thus the value of `5` represents the constrained minimum...

To get this answer with your code, one has to fix the constraint. In your case, you are summing all the components of `w*x` shifted by 1. Here, it could however happen that one particular component is much larger than 1 and therefore its contribution into the sum could mask other components which are only slightly smaller than 1 (for example if `x=[2, 0.25]`, `w=2`, then `w*x-1=[3,-0.5]` and the sum is therefore positive even though the constraint is violated). To rectify this, one could sum only those components of `w*x-1` which are negative, i.e., those which violate the constraint:

```
def con(w,x,y,alpha):
    return np.minimum(w*x - 1, 0).sum()
```